# excel formula keeps revalidating when any cell value is changed

Tags: validation, selection, formula, dropdown

**Task:**
Multiple selection from a drop down list, selected values displayed joined with "x"-es in another cell.

My solution was with a formula.

It intended to do this:

(1) Drop down list (Cell: C253):

(2) lookup formula in another cell(Cell: E253)(hidden, protected):
  Formula:

```
    =VLOOKUP(C253,H1:I126,2,FALSE)
```

(3) displaying selected value(s) joined with "x" (Cell: C254):
  Joining formula:

```
    =IF(ISERROR(E253)=TRUE,FALSE,IF(C254=FALSE,E253,CONCATENATE(C254,"x",E253)))
```

Expected Result:
 If nothing has been selected yet >> E253=Error and C254=FALSE
 If first selection has been made >> E253=Selection and C254=Selection1
 If second, third... etc. selection is made >> E253=Selection and C254=Selection1 xSelection2 ... xSelectionN
 If drop down list selection in C253 is deleted (reset to start over) >> E253=Error and C254=FALSE

The formula works fine except that each time a cell (any cell) is changed on the worksheet, data validation runs again and the last selected drop down list item is added(=joined with "x") to the text in the result cell.

For that reason, i tried to use the same validation formula in a VBA code which runs when the target cell is selected but there is always some error when i try to use the formula in the VBA code.
It obviously not the right solution anyway.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has an option to disable automatic calculation. Will that help?  Google search excel stop automatic calculation.

Comment: It won't help because it would disable the execution of the formulas in the other cells.